# (Leetcode) Brick wall

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, programming-challenge

I would like to know whether I could make my solution to this [Leetcode challenge](https://leetcode.com/problems/brick-wall/) much faster.

> *There is a brick wall in front of you. The wall is rectangular and has
>   several rows of bricks. The bricks have the same heights but different
>   widths. You want to draw a vertical line from the **top** to the
>   **bottom** and cross the **least** bricks.*
>
> *The brick wall is represented by a list of rows. Each row is a list of
>   integers representing the width of each brick in this row from left to
>   right.*
>
> *If your line goes through the edge of a brick, then the brick is not
>   considered as crossed. You need to find out how to draw the line to
>   cross the least bricks and return the number of crossed bricks.*
>
> ***You cannot draw a line just along one of the two vertical edges of the wall, in which case the line will obviously cross no bricks.***
>
> ***Note -***
>
> - *The width sum of bricks in different rows are the same and won't exceed `INT_MAX`.*
> - *The number of bricks in each row is in the range `[1, 10,000]`. The height of the wall is in the range `[1, 10,000]`. The total number of
>     bricks in the wall won't exceed `20,000`.*
>
> ***Example -***
>
> ```
> Input: [[1,2,2,1],
>         [3,1,2],
>         [1,3,2],
>         [2,4],
>         [3,1,2],
>         [1,3,1,1]]
>
> Output: 2
> ```
>
> ***Explanation -***
>
> [image]

Here is my solution to this challenge -

```
import collections    

def least_bricks(wall):
    return len(wall) - max(collections.Counter(sum(row[:i + 1]) for row in wall for i in range(len(row[:-1]))).values(), default = 0)
```

Here is the time taken for the example output -

```
%timeit least_bricks([[1,2,2,1], [3,1,2], [1,3,2], [2,4], [3,1,2], [1,3,1,1]])

>>> 13 µs ± 1.07 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Here is my Leetcode result (85 test cases) -

> [image]

Taken from - *https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter* -

> *A Counter is a dict subclass for counting hashable objects. It is a
>   collection where elements are stored as dictionary keys and their
>   counts are stored as dictionary values. Counts are allowed to be any
>   integer value including zero or negative counts. The Counter class is
>   similar to bags or multisets in other languages.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a lot of repeated summing taking place in this part:

```
(sum(row[:i + 1]) for row in wall for i in range(len(row[:-1])))
```

So this is summing the first i+1 elements in the row, with an upper bound that steps through all values except the last. If the row was [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], these are the sums:

- 1
- 1+2 = 3
- 1+2+3 = 6
- 1+2+3+4 = 10

The sums differ, but only by the last term. It would therefore save effort to use a running sum instead, only adding that last term each time:

- 1
- 1+2 = 3
- 3+3 = 6
- 6+4 = 10

This can be done with [itertools.accumulate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate):

```
(s for row in wall for s in itertools.accumulate(row[:-1]))
```

Another thing in your code that this approach solves is the i+1 summing. Instead of having this addition performed on every iteration, you could iterate through the correct values directly with `for i in range(1, len(row))`. But using accumulate, this is already taken care of.

Answer (score 3):

## Counter

Great use of `Counter`. One thing that can be improved, is to use `most_common` instead of `max`.

If `edges` is the Counter of all the edges in the wall, `_, max_edges = edges.most_common(1)` gives you the index with the most edges, and how many edges it has. Since this is the right side of the wall, you need the 2nd most common element: `edges.most_common(2)[1]`

## aggregating the counter

Python is batteries included. Whenever you want to do advanced iteration, it can pay to look at the `itertools` module. For this, you can use `accumulate` (as @sedsarq notes in his answer) and `chain`.

```
edges = collections.Counter(
    chain.from_iterable(accumulate(row) for row in wall)
)
```

---

```
def least_bricks2(wall):
    edges = collections.Counter(
        chain.from_iterable(accumulate(row) for row in wall)
    )
    if len(edges) == 1: # only one brick wide
        return len(wall)
    _, max_edges = edges.most_common(2)[1]  #skipping the right edge of the wall
    return len(wall) - max_edges
```

Comment: To be pedantic, you need to check for the case where the counter only has one element. That can occur if there is only one width of brick, for instance the testcase [[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2]]

Comment: You are correct. Fixed that